# How to inherited variable content from base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

User class as Base class and Student class as derived class from User.

```
class User{
protected:
    string name;
    string id;
public:
    ...set and get function..

    virtual void Serialize(ofstream& fstream){
    fstream << id << "," << name << ",\n";
    }
}

class Student :public User{
private:
    string school;
public:
    ...set and get function...

    virtual void Serialize(ofstream& fstream){
    fstream << id << "," << name << "," << school << ",\n";
    }
}
```

Here are the main class.

```
void save(Save& i_save){
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("save.csv", ios::app);
    i_save.Serialize(outfile);
}


int main() {

    User current_user;
    User current_student;

    string in_name;
    string in_id;
    string in_school;

    cin >> in_name;
    current_user.setName(in_name);

    cin >> in_id;
    current_user.setID(in_id);

    cin >> in_school;
    current_student.setSchool(in_school);

    save(current_student);

    return 0;

}
```

Example input: SAM <- name, S02 <- id, and Rock <- school.

I want to save all this input in the CSV file, but when I run, it only saves school content without name and id.

How to solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: This `current_student.setSchool(user_user_school);` should not compile. Not only because of the typo but because `User` has no method `setSchool`, `current_student` has to be of type `Student`. Furthermore, what is the `Save` class? This is important to know. Please always post a [mre].

Comment: Your `main()` function   (it is NOT a class, as you describe) creates two distinct objects,  `current_user` and `current_student`.   The entered `in_name` and `in_id` are passed to member functions of `current_user`, and the only data passed to `current_student` is `in_school`.      That is why the "school content" is saved without name and id - they are stored in different objects.   To fix, remove the definition of `current_user` and change all references to `current_user`  (like `current_user.setID(in_id)`) so they refer to `current_student` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main function:

```
Student current_student;

User* current_user = &current_student;
```

use `current_user` to call all functions.
Based on the above code I can suggest only this.

Currently, you are using the two different objects created on stack and saving Student object data.